# In JSONSchema, how do I validate that an object has only one of two properties, or neither property?

Tags: jsonschema

I've found several questions similar to my situation, but none I thought were the same. I have an object that can have properties "address" and "geoPoint". It can have either *or neither* of these properties, just not both. How could this be done with JSONSchema?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is with `dependencies`.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "dependencies": {
    "address": { "not": { "required": ["geoPoint"] } },
    "geoPoint": { "not": { "required": ["address"] } }
  }
}
```